# What is the easiest way to check if aerospike set is empty from python?

Tags: python, aerospike

I don't see a method in a [Python client](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html) which checks if the given set is empty.

As documentation [says](https://aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/sets/index.html#truncating-a-set-in-a-namespace) from the command line I can use:

```
asinfo -h <host> -v 'sets/<namespace>/<set>'
```

but it is for a single host only.

Another way is to look at the output of:

```
asadm -h <host> -e 'info set'
```

How would you implement such a method in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "info" API in the client: https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.info_all

```
client.info_all("sets/<namespace>/<set>")
```

Then sum the stat you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my python implementation:

```py
def _info_result_prop_value(info_result, prop_name, default):
    result_split = info_result.split(':')
    return next((s.strip().split('=', 2)[1] for s in result_split
                 if s.strip().startswith(f'{prop_name}=')), default)


def count_objects(client, ns, set_name):
    count = 0
    for info_result in client.info_all(f"sets/{ns}/{set_name}").values():
        count += int(_info_result_prop_value(info_result[1], 'objects', '0'))
    return count


def is_empty_set(client, ns, set_name):
    return count_objects(client, ns, set_name) == 0
```